# ProtractorTestResults.trx file is not generating in angular testing report

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am new in end-to-end testing, I am generating the report for my E2E test cases my code in config is

```
  onPrepare: 
function () {

  require('protractor-trx-reporter');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
  new jasmine.TrxReporter('ProtractorTestResults.trx'));

}
```

already install protractor-trx-reporter via npm but still not able to get the ProtractorTestResults.trx file.

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: gunderson :- no error cmd showing message "setting output file to ProtractorTestResults.trx " but trx file is not generating